# How to access DataSet From BLL in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

I'm sorry for the question, but I'm new with the BLL :(

I have my DAL with a dsUsers.xsd created.

Now I'm trying to develop the BLL for UserBLL,

I realized that in some examples on the web, they make reference to the table adapters like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using dsUserTableAdapters;
```

But every time I trying to add the last part of the above code, I get nothing starting with that name,

Do I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to your DAL library to your BLL. Then, you can reference the dataset like so:

```
using MyDal.MyDataSetNamespace;
```

You can then create an object of your dataset type

```
MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet();
```

EDIT: To add a reference of your DAL to your BLL, right click the BLL project and choose `Add Reference`. In the window that pops up, choose the `Projects` tab and select your DAL project.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but, how to add a reference to my DAL library to my BLL?

Comment: oh, that's why, I'm not using projects for DAL and BLL, is mandatory to create projects for them, in order to make references between them? Cause I have an example here of a website, that works with DAL and BLL, without creating projects for them.

Comment: No, it's not mandatory, just recommended. How are you handling it now? Are you DAL and BLL classes in separate folders? If they are, you'll just need to add a using in your BLL to the namespace of your DAL (which is most likely the folder it's in.) Something like `using MyProject.DALFolder`.